# Upgrading Debian Squeeze to Wheezy - Should updatedb.conf be kept or replaced?

Tags: virtual-machine, upgrade, debian

A similar question to [Upgrading Debian Squeeze To Wheezy - Should conf' files be kept or replaced?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63814/upgrading-debian-squeeze-to-wheezy-should-conf-files-be-kept-or-replaced), but in my case it concerns a different conf file and I am not on Linode.

I am upgrading a VMWare virtual machine that I intend to use as a server, from Debian 6 to Debian 7. The Squeeze install has been done by the company that provides the machine. Besides the possible customizations they *may* have done, I haven't done any customization or installs at all.

In any case, I updated my `/etc/apt/sources.list` and I did `apt-get update; apt-get dist-upgrade`, during the process of which, I get the following prompt:

```
Configuration file `/etc/updatedb.conf'
==> Modified (by you or by a script) since installation.
==> Package distributor has shipped an updated version.
   What would you like to do about it ?  Your options are:
    Y or I  : install the package maintainer's version
    N or O  : keep your currently-installed version
      D     : show the differences between the versions
      Z     : start a shell to examine the situation
 The default action is to keep your current version.
*** updatedb.conf (Y/I/N/O/D/Z) [default=N] ?
```

on which I chose `D` and the output is:

```
--- /etc/updatedb.conf  2011-06-06 16:32:11.000000000 +0200
+++ /etc/updatedb.conf.dpkg-new 2010-09-25 10:12:26.000000000 +0200
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
 PRUNE_BIND_MOUNTS="yes"
 # PRUNENAMES=".git .bzr .hg .svn"
 PRUNEPATHS="/tmp /var/spool /media"
-PRUNEFS="NFS nfs nfs4 rpc_pipefs afs binfmt_misc proc smbfs autofs iso9660 ncpfs coda devpts ftpfs devfs mfs shfs sysfs cifs lustre_lite tmpfs usbfs udf fuse.glusterfs fuse.sshfs vmhgfs"
+PRUNEFS="NFS nfs nfs4 rpc_pipefs afs binfmt_misc proc smbfs autofs iso9660 ncpfs coda devpts ftpfs devfs mfs shfs sysfs cifs lustre_lite tmpfs usbfs udf fuse.glusterfs fuse.sshfs curlftpfs"
```

Any suggestions on what these mean and what I should do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you host added `vmhgfs`, which is [a VMWare filesystem](https://serverfault.com/questions/27500/what-is-vmhgfs). So, likely, they're exporting something to you, possibly a fairly large filesystem, and don't want it to be crawled by updatedb.

Wheezy's default apparently adds `curlftpfs` as well (you can tell by scanning across the line in the diff, and seeing that's the only part that differs).

So, the obvious approach would be to hit Z, and edit the file to include both `vmhgfs` and `curlftpfs`, exit, then answer N (as you've manually merged the files).